# Minimum oriented bounding box corner point extraction

Tags: c++, computer-vision, point-cloud-library, bounding-box

I am using the following code to get minimum oriented bounding box of a point cloud with the aim to extract all 8 corner points of BB.

http://codextechnicanum.blogspot.de/2015/04/find-minimum-oriented-bounding-box-of.html

I found another piece of code to extract this corner point information for example as follows. What I am not sure is what should be the rotational_matrix_OBB and position variables from the code above.

Any suggestions please.

Thanks in advance.

```
Eigen::Vector3f position (position_OBB.x, position_OBB.y, position_OBB.z);

Eigen::Matrix3f rotational_matrix_OBB;


Eigen::Vector3f p1 (minPoint.x, minPoint.y, minPoint.z);

p1 = rotational_matrix_OBB * p1 + position;

pcl::PointXYZ pt1 (p1 (0), p1 (1), p1 (2));

std::cout << "pt1: " << pt1 << std::endl;
```

Comment: The rotation matrix is self-explanatory - it's the matrix required to rotate all the points from being axis-aligned to the intended orientation

Comment: right thanks. It seems to me                                                     
 Eigen::Matrix3f eigenVectorsPCA = eigen_solver.eigenvectors();     Is it ?